# Is it allowed to use ActiveRecord functions without primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was storing a log of activities using an ActiveRecord model and it seems that one can dispose of the primary key:

```
class NetLog < ApplicationRecord

def self.primary_key
    nil
end
```

I can create records, query for them, and loop across results. Surely I will unable to update, but it is a log, no updates expected. So it seems to work for my purposes. Now I wonder, am I using a documented option?

EDIT: Ah, I see, the problem was that also my ApplicationRecord (legacy) likes to set a primary_key, and then it seems to override the setting in the migration.

So perhaps a cleaner question is: How does the setting of self.primary_key interacts with the settings in db/schema.rb? My guess now is that if no primary_key is defined, schema.rb is examined to set the primary_key, but that if a primary_key getter is defined, schema.rb "`id: false`" is ignored

Comment: Whats the point of not having an id? Just because you're not updating the records it seems like a stupid assumption that you won't ever want to fetch a specific row. "am I using a documented option?" No, AR is not built to work with models without a PK and you will get a ton of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways, but why have a `id` column in the first place if you want the value to be `nil`? You can create a table without primary key using Rails migrations

```
create_table :net_logs, id: false do |t|
  t.string ...
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah, I see, problem was that my legacy ApplicationRecord was already setting a non null self.primary_key, which supersedes the id: false migration